# Drupal 8 theme includes a basic page that I can't remove via block layout

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

If it helps, I am using the "Gavias Uxima" theme, and although I have disabled or removed all blocks from the "Main Content" region, there is still a...view?...of a Basic Page node within that region. If I delete all Basic Page nodes, I get 'page could not be found' at the end of that region.

Since I see that error or content even when there are no blocks assigned to the region, now I don't know where to look to stop displaying the Basic Page.

I am trying to create a dead simple setup with no additional content, so I would like the extra, required?, Basic Page and its error message to go away completely.

### Header:

### // My Header

### Main Content:

// No blocks are assigned to this region, but I still see the Basic Page content below, or an error message if I also delete all Basic Page content:

### The requested page could not be found

### Footer:

// My Footer

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with that theme but have you checked if the view is being loaded directly into a template file? Perhaps using something like [Twig Tweak's](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) `drupal_view` function in one of the page or region templates.